# Terraform: prevent recreating rds cluster during each apply with ignore_changes

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

I managed to prevent recreating rds cluster during each apply by setting ignore_changes = all, but it is only one parameter -- cluster_members -- that changes. Setting only this parameter to ignore_changes doesn't work -- cluster gets destroyed and created again. Could someone help me understand why it doesn't work please?

```
resource "aws_rds_cluster" "aurora_cluster" {

  cluster_identifier     = local.cluster_id
  final_snapshot_identifier       = try(data.aws_db_cluster_snapshot.start_from_snapshot[0].id, null)
  engine                 = "aurora-mysql"
  engine_version         = var.rds_engine_version
  engine_mode            = "provisioned"
  master_username        = var.rds_master_username
  master_password        = var.rds_master_password
  db_subnet_group_name   = aws_db_subnet_group.rds-subnet-group.name
  vpc_security_group_ids = concat([aws_security_group.rds_inbound.id], var.external_sgs)
  apply_immediately               = true
  skip_final_snapshot             = true
  deletion_protection             = var.deletion_protection
  backup_retention_period         = var.backup_retention_period
  enabled_cloudwatch_logs_exports = var.rds_cloudwatch_logs
  kms_key_id                      = data.aws_kms_alias.rds_kms_key.arn
  storage_encrypted        = true
  db_cluster_parameter_group_name = aws_rds_cluster_parameter_group.rds-cluster-params.name
  db_instance_parameter_group_name = aws_db_parameter_group.rds-instance-params.name
  tags = merge(
    local.common_tags,
    {
      Description = "RDS cluster ..."
    }
  )
  lifecycle {
    ignore_changes = [cluster_members]
  }
}
```

Terraform plan:

```
# aws_rds_cluster.aurora_cluster has changed
  ~ resource aws_rds_cluster aurora_cluster {
      ~ cluster_members                     = [
          + rds-1-1,
          + rds-1-2,
        ]
        id                                  = rds-1
        tags                                = {
            Description      = RDS cluster 1
            EnvName          = env
            EnvType          = dev
            ...
        }
        # (37 unchanged attributes hidden)
    }


Unless you have made equivalent changes to your configuration, or ignored the
relevant attributes using ignore_changes, the following plan may include
actions to undo or respond to these changes.
```

Comment: Why do you change `cluster_members` outside of TF?

Comment: @Marcin because apparently there is a bug that I submitted to terraform that causes terraform failure during cluster instances creation in Milan region (maybe because Aurora global database is not available in Milan). So I had to create instances with Ansible and import them to terraform state. Import works, I get "aws_rds_cluster_instance.aurora_cluster_instance[0] will be updated in-place" message in terraform plan, but regarding cluster -- "aws_rds_cluster.aurora_cluster must be replaced"